# Run VisualBasicScript from keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, python, vbscript

I've written a bat file to execute a python script, and to avoid popping up of cmd, I'm calling it through a vbs script. Now I need to execute the python script through vbs script but using keyboard shortcuts. I've searched online, but couldn't come up with a convincing answer. Found a lot of third party softwares, but don't want to use them. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a vbscript example for creating a shortcut of the notepad application and setting up a Hotkey as `Ctrl+Alt+E`

```
Option Explicit
Dim Application_Path
Application_Path = "C:\windows\notepad.exe"
Call Shortcut(Application_Path ,"")
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Shortcut(Application_Path,ShortcutName)
    Dim objShell,fso,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab,strCurDir
    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    strCurDir = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
    MyTab = Split(Application_Path,"\")
    If ShortcutName = "" Then
        ShortcutName = MyTab(UBound(MyTab))
    End if
    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\" & ShortcutName & ".lnk")
    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote(Application_Path)
    ObjShortCut.WindowStyle = 1
    ObjShortCut.Hotkey = "Ctrl+Alt+e"
    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = "notepad.exe, 0"
    objShortCut.Save
End Sub
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function Dblquote(str)
    Dblquote = chr(34) & str & chr(34)
End Function
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wish in effect to execute some program with arguments, whether this
program is `cscript` for VBS or python.

The simplest solution is to right-click the desktop, select *New > Shortcut*,
enter the entire command-line and click Next and give it a good name.

This will create an icon on the desktop with the given name.
Right-click it and select Properties. In the dialog that opens in the *Shortcut*
tab, click inside *Shortcut key:*, press the wanted shortcut key, then
click OK.

The created icon can now be invoked by this shortcut key.